# Is it possible to change a class by hooking into bean definitions?

Tags: java, spring, javassist

I like to change a 3rd party class in a web-application using javassist. The class gets loaded when the spring web application context intialization gets called by `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`. I tried a custom `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` but it seems to kick in too late:

`javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader ... duplicate class definition for name: "SomeClass"`

I guess it can be done by replacing the `ContextLoaderListener` by a custom one changing the class right before initializing the beans. If somehow possible, I would prefer not touching web.xml at all.

Hence, my question is whether there is a way registering a callback which executes before any classes of bean definitions load.

Answer (score 0):

you might try implementing `PriorityOrdered` on your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to achieve an effect similiar to the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which is invoked before other beans (so that it can load up and make available, properties that can be use in bean definitions.

have a look at the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for a pattern to reuse.

Comment: I have not tried it, but I am fairly sure it won't work. Spring has to load classes in order to find out about PriorityOrdered. Hence, the "wrong" class is already loaded when the custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor kicks in.

Comment: ah, sorry - missed that bit - you're trying to prevent it from being loaded at all in preference of a replacement?

Comment: Exactly ! I wan't spring to pick up the changed class.

Comment: how is Spring picking up the legacy now?  Is it XML config or JavaConfig?

Comment: Its XML, but I guess that does not matter as discovering annotations still loads the class.